# Migrate Microsoft Access application to... well, that is the question?

Tags: ms-access, forms, report

I developed a medium sized MS Access application back in 2004. Over the years it has grown old and my small bugfixes and improvements don't cut it anymore.

I always hear people yammering about how bad Access is and how it is not modern yadda,yadda. I'm quite happy with it and it does what it is supposed to do (Provide a stable frontend for a simple database).

My application uses lots of custom forms with subforms and lots of VBA code to do this and that. The most important part of the application is actually to provide the data for Word Mail Merges and to print badges and other material for a conference (via Access reports). And exactly this printing integration is why I can't think of any alternatives.
Any web based solution will be a hassle to create nice looking reports (or at least not with the easy of Access) - create pixel perfect layouts and mold them into PDFs, direct printing FTW. Any Windows Forms application will take long to develop and ultimately I would just be recreating functionality of MS Access (e.g. together with SSRS).

Can you think of any alternatives I have missed? I am basically just looking for ideas.

Comment: Can you give us a clearer idea of what's wrong with Access? Is it just the look-and-feel, or are the some database-type problems too, or some things you want to add / improve but Access won't let you, etc.

Comment: I think one of the reasons that some people complain about Access is that they are brought in to situations where Access was an inappropriate solution, or has become inappropriate. If you application is still working for the users, is there any reason to change? From my own experience, I know that users often do not like change, it slows them down. Change is usually good for people trying to sell something.

Comment: *"[...]they are brought in to situations where Access was an inappropriate solution, or has become inappropriate[...]"* <-- this. Access is fine for small solutions, but is bad for Enterprise solutions (in a sentence). As I said, for me it is working - I did not hear complaints. I just wish I wouldn't have to work with special ODBC data connectors to connect to an external MySQL database (it's all so easy in PHP ;-). I wish my users could have an offline database which is synced via a web frontend to all users and can be viewed online without degredation. Not possible without lot's of work;-)

Comment: You might like to look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Comment: Thanks Remou, I know about Access 2010 Web Databases - however they are too limited as they don't support all the VBA code I have and the forms are also limited. Nice feature for a simple database, not for my use case though ;-)

Comment: Personally, I've come to two conclusions: 1) Nothing touches MS Access as a RAD tool for developing *desktop* front-end interfaces, and 2) There is no *good* way to develop a web front-end using MS Access or its associated tools.  I've had a few projects that required a public-facing web front-end and a private, intranet-facing desktop front-end.  I use Access for the desktop version and a good web framework for the web version.  I guess my advice is, **don't migrate your existing Access app, *enhance* it with a separate web front-end**.  Especially since you already have a working Access app.

Comment: mwolfe: Thanks for the support. It's good to hear a second opinion because I think that is exactly what I am doing right now: Access Front-End and a PHP based web front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you use built in functionality in Access the best path might be to not abandon Access but rather to rebuild the application as a new Access application.

Start by breaking out parts of the application to classes to get all related code together and clean up that code.

This way you could still use the parts of access you really have use for but the code will be better.

Also take a look on a book I like, [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)

[Here is some other talk about this book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141643/has-anyone-read-robert-martins-last-book-clean-code).

Refactoring code like this is also a good way to get to know all the intricate parts of it  ;)

And you will not risk losing any functionality.

If you later get to build it on another platform, most of the refactoring would probably be reusable.

Comment: I know about Clean Code and the Clean Code initiative. They're pretty strict with their badges and the like... The application is not bad programming per se, it actually IS already all in classes and adheres to normal programming standards (naming, spaghetti code etc.) - it just "looks" old and I would redesign many of the UI concepts. Your suggestion to not abandon Access and rebuild the application is what I am planning on doing right now.

Comment: You don't want to make the Netscape error, though, and start over from scratch. I make my living redesigning old Access apps, some of them developed by others, some of them my own old apps. There are a lot of advantages to that approach, though you really do have to know Access well to get the most out of it.